# BreakIterator.preceding fails in Android V2?

Tags: android

The following code works just fine with Android 4, but causes an IllegalArgumentException in Android 2.

Any clues?

```
Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en_UK"); 
final BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(currentLocale);
boundary.setText("a"); 
int thisThrowsExceptionInVersion2 = boundary.preceding(1);
```

Exception:

```
08-08 22:29:14.414: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
08-08 22:29:14.414: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.validateOffset(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:74)
08-08 22:29:14.414: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.preceding(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:158)
08-08 22:29:14.414: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at kalle.palle.namespace.KallePalleActivity.onCreate(KallePalleActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: You mean Android 4.X and 2.X right?  Not API levels 4 and 2 obviously I'm assuming.  Took me a couple minutes to figure out what you meant by that lol.

Comment: Yes, Android API level 10 fails on this. It seems to work on android-15. I am looking for confirmation that this is the cause of my issue, not some subtle error in my code or use of BreakIterator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is the validateOffset in Gingerbread code

```
private void validateOffset(int offset) {
    CharacterIterator it = wrapped.getText();
    if (offset < it.getBeginIndex() || offset >= it.getEndIndex()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

and in ICS code is as below

```
private void validateOffset(int offset) {
    CharacterIterator it = wrapped.getText();
    if (offset < it.getBeginIndex() || offset > it.getEndIndex()) {
        String message = "Valid range is [" + it.getBeginIndex() + " " + it.getEndIndex() + "]";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }
}
```

`>=`  has been changed to `>` . The end offset checking seems to be wrong in 2.X devices. This is especially true in your case where the offset you are passing to `preceding` overlaps with the end index of the string. This seems to be bug in framework.
You can find the source in AOSP code at libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/text/RuleBasedBreakIterator.java.
 Here's the [Gingerbread code](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/text/RuleBasedBreakIterator.java#71) and here's the [ICS code](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/text/RuleBasedBreakIterator.java#50)